# Reset a hard bounce

Tags: marketing-cloud

Text task.

A customers EmailAddress (customerID = SubscriberKey) hard bounced several times and turns to undeliverable. The customer changes his email address.

Questions
1. Does the customer get emails?
2. If not, how can the hard bounce be reset automatically?

Thanks and kind regards
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The customer's status would still be listed as undeliverable - to my knowledge there is no 'automatic' process that will reactivate anyone in SFMC.

There are a couple ways you can reactivate manually though.

1. Via API call - [ListSubscriber Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/listsubscriber.htm). This is a bit complex and requires a developer, but is likely the easiest method.
2. Via SSJS function -[Subscriber.Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUpdate.htm). This is a bit simpler, but still will likely require a developer. This will also require either a script activity or a cloud page to run.
3. There are some things you can do with SQL and export/import activities or via the UI, but I have found that these are only really reasonable for specific use cases.
4. **My Recommendation** Assuming that you are not a developer and you don't want to bother a developer for a single record, the easiest way is to:

   - Create a CSV file with two fields (Subscriberkey | Status).
   - Write "Active" in status column.
   - Do an import into AllSubs with this file
   - Set the import type to Update.
   - Make sure to map only those two fields.

This will then change the status for the subscriber to Active and he will now receive your emails again.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. Very helpful.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please be sure to mark it as answered for easy reference if anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log in to the Marketing Cloud application
2. Go to Email Studio | Email | Subscribers | All Subscribers
3. Click the Search button
4. Select Email Address from the Search where: drop-down field
5. Enter the subscriber's email address in the Is equal to: field and click the Find Now button
6. Click to highlight the subscriber from the search results list and click the View Properties link
7. In the General tab, click the Unsubscribe from all button
8. Click the OK button in the dialog box
9. In the General tab, click the Activate button (activates only on the All Subscribers list)
10. To activate the subscriber on individual lists, select the List tab.
11. Select the desired list and click the Details button
12. Click the Activate button to reactivate the subscriber on the specified list
13. Click the OK button in the dialog box to exit

I figured this also worked :) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268698&type=1